# Replacing words with for cycle in python

Tags: python, for-loop, replace

I'd like to replace the word "anywhere" in the link below with each word of the list_airports. With my code I obtain only "https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-BCN/20210809,20210831". Can you help me? Thank you

```
list_airports = ['BCN', 'REU', 'RMU', 'VLC', 'IBZ', 'ALC', 'AGP', 'MAD']

link = "https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-anywhere/20210809,20210831"

for airport in list_airports:

     link = link.replace('anywhere', airport, 1)

print(link)
```

Comment: You are overwriting your original `link`. Instead save it to a new variable `new_link = link.replace('anywhere', airport, 1)` and `print` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to upvote this answer.

For your understanding. Do not override your actual input string.

```
for airport in list_airports:
     temp = link.replace('anywhere', airport, 1)
     print(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
link.replace("anywhere", "-".join(list_airports))
```

Output:

```
https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-BCN-REU-RMU-VLC-IBZ-ALC-AGP-MAD/20210809,20210831
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to split the stings and reconnect them using the desired sub-string:

```
from itertools import repeat
list_airports = ['BCN', 'REU', 'RMU', 'VLC', 'IBZ', 'ALC', 'AGP', 'MAD']
link = "https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-anywhere/20210809,20210831"

links= list(repeat(link, len(list_airports))) #creates list of identical links
l1=[i.split('anywhere',3) for i in links] #splits them at 'anywhere'
answer=[list_airports[i].join(l1[i]) for i in range(len(list_airports))] #reconstructs with airport_list as joiner

answer
```

**Output:**

```
['https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-BCN/20210809,20210831',
 'https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-REU/20210809,20210831',
 'https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-RMU/20210809,20210831',
 'https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-VLC/20210809,20210831',
 'https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-IBZ/20210809,20210831',
 'https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-ALC/20210809,20210831',
 'https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-AGP/20210809,20210831',
 'https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-MAD/20210809,20210831']
```